# Hosting Jenkins and Web App on tomcat server at the same time

Tags: centos, tomcat, jenkins

I have a web app running on one tomcat server on 443 port. I want to set up Jenkins on same tomcat server and that too on same port i.e. 443. Is it possible to have Jenkins and Web on the same server?

Answer (score 1):

You can have different web (or, for what it matters, any kind of) services on the same host, but they need to run on different ports. So if you run Tomcat on TCP 443 you can't run Jenkins on the same port.

If your aim is to mostly use Jenkins, you should set up Tomcat to use another port, either 8080 for HTTP or 8443 for HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I have been succeeded setting up Jenkins on Tomcat which is running on 443. This has solved my purpose of having web app and Jenkins on same port